# How to count hitting/ visiting number of page except by refreshing or reloading?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have developed a site where I want to count hit when the page url is clicked but this should not count on page reloading or refreshing. I have already visited many site but not got the appropriate solution. Kindly help me to get over this.
 It would be very helpful if I received solution with some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like this:

```
    public class HitCounter extends HttpServlet {

    long hitCounter;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    incrementHitCounter();
    HttpSession usersession = request.getSession();
    usersession.setAttribute("HITCOUNTER", hitCounter);
}

private void incrementHitCounter() {

    /**
     * Here I am increasing counter each time this HitCounterServlet is called. 
     * Now I want total number of visitor on per day basis. 
    */

    hitCounter = hitCounter + 1;

    /**
     * You can add additional logic here.
     *
    */
}
}
```

Comment: will this code increment the hitCounter on reloading or refreshing the page... if yes... I dont want hitCounter to be incremented on each reloading or refreshing the page... Kindly look at this.. cuz i have already done such kind of activity